# Problems running Spark SQL in a loop

Tags: scala, caching, apache-spark-sql

I run out of memory when I run a Spark SQL query in a loop in Scala. I use Spark 3.1.2 in local mode with 8GB driver/executor memory. I know that Spark DataFrames are not suitable for programs with iterations since they may form long lineage chains of hundreds of operations but I always assumed that this can be fixed with careful caching to break the lineage chain (which may be impossible). I understand that caching in DataFrames is lazy so it is only fully completed after an action. So, here is a simplified version of my program:

```
var P = spark.sql("select id, 1.0 as val from range(1000)")
val Q = spark.sql("select id, 2.0 as val from range(1000)")
val E = spark.sql("select id, 3.0 as val from range(1000)")
E.cache.count
Q.cache.count
E.createOrReplaceTempView("E")
Q.createOrReplaceTempView("Q")
for ( i <- 1 to 20 ) {
    val oldP = P
    oldP.createOrReplaceTempView("P")
    P = spark.sql("""select Q.id, P.val*Q.val*E.val as val
                     from Q join E on Q.id=E.id join P on P.id=Q.id""")
    spark.catalog.dropTempView("P")
    P.cache.count
    oldP.unpersist
}
P.count
```

The `P.cache.count` is supposed to force caching since it has an action. I have also used `P.cache.write.mode("overwrite").format("noop").save()` with the same results. When I run it for a large number of iterations (>10) it runs out of memory. The Spark UI shows that there are always 3 RDDs cached (E, Q, and P), so caching and unpersisting work fine. So my question is: why Spark runs out of memory for this program? In general, is there any way to break the lineage of a long chain of transformations in dataFrames, like Spark RDDs do? Thanks!

Comment: You're asking Spark to cache multiple data frames, and your cached data frames are not being reused. What's the reason you're doing this in a loop? Is it because you're analyzing this behavior or is it how your actual code works? There seems to be no reason to use the loop and the data frames can be cached just once...

Comment: If you have a loop of 100s of iterations and you don't cache you'll get a physical plan with 100s of joins (all operations are chained together). There is also a cyclic dependency where a new P is compute from the P from the previous step. DataFrames cannot handle 100s of joins efficiently as you can see if you run the program without caching. Or maybe it's the cyclic dependency that confuses the optimizer. I know that caching is used when multiple actions work on the same DataFrame but the intent here is to break these 100s of joins into manageable small joins over cached results.

Comment: This program is just an example - it doesn't do anything useful. My actual program is matrix factorization where you get the factor matrices P and Q from a matrix R. This, and most ML programs, require iteration.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution so far is to dump the data into a file and read the file. This will break the lineage of the thousands of transformations throughout the loop. Let me know if you have a better solution. Caching and checkpointing don't break the lineage. So let's say that you have a loop with n steps that has cyclic dependencies, such as `P=f(P)`, and let's say that Spark DataFrames can do up to k steps without crushing. Then, one solution is:

```
    val n = 1000              // number of iterations
    val k = 10                // number of loop steps that Spark can handle
    val pdir = "/tmp/cache/"  // directory to dump parquet data

    var P = spark.sql("select id, 1.0 as val from range(1000)")
    val Q = spark.sql("select id, 2.0 as val from range(1000)")
    val E = spark.sql("select id, 3.0 as val from range(1000)")
    E.createOrReplaceTempView("E")
    Q.createOrReplaceTempView("Q")
    for ( i <- 1 to n ) {
       P.createOrReplaceTempView("P")
       P = spark.sql("""select Q.id, P.val*Q.val*E.val as val
                        from Q join E on Q.id=E.id join P on P.id=Q.id""")
       spark.catalog.dropTempView("P")
       if (i%k == 0) {
         P.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(pdir+i)
         P = spark.read.parquet(pdir+i)
       }
    }
    P.count
```

Every k steps, it will dump P to a file and read it again. It works fine on my workstation.